# Write psutil query result to csv

Tags: python-3.x

I am still new to python. I am using psutil documentation's recipe to find process by name. Now, I am trying to save the result to a csv file. However, I am stuck at writing csv with the correct format.

I tried to use zip() for the 3 string objects like below:

```py
rows = zip(processCreationTime, processName, processCmd)
with open('/var/log/supervisor_process.log', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

The whole script;

```py
import psutil
import time
import csv

def find_procs_by_name(name):
    "Return a list of processes matching 'name'."
    ls = []
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name']):
        if p.info['name'] == name:
            ls.append(p)
    return ls

def main():
    listProc = find_procs_by_name('supervisord')

    if len(listProc) > 0:
        for elem in listProc:
            processName = elem['name']
            processCreationTime = time..strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(elem['create_time']))
            processCmd = elem['cmdline']['0']
            print((processCreationTime, processName, processCmd))
            # CSV code here
            ###########
    else:
        print('Not found')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The csv file should have the same content as the print statement without the bracket:

```
'2019-06-12', 'supervisord', '/usr/bin/python'
'2019-06-12', 'supervisord', '/usr/bin/python'
'2019-07-15', 'supervisord', '/usr/bin/python'
```

I have very little experience with data structure so any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured this out by read more into the docs and see some examples of the writer function. i.e how to "append" strings in to each of the row after every loop.

```py
def main():
    # Create and/or clear existing file content then add headers
    with open('/var/log/supervisor_process.log', 'w+') as f:
        header = csv.writer(f)
        header.writerow(['hostname','create_time','name','cmdline'])
   ....
        # CSV code
        with open('/var/log/supervisor_process.log', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([myhost, processCreationTime, processName, processCmd])
```